# How to scrape if the whole page changes?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

with this can reached the link 3 days ago:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    

html_url23 = "http://streamstat.net/videoplayer.cgi?sid=148177550&ext=.m3u8"
html_response = requests.get(html_url23)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_response.text, 'html.parser')
for vid in soup.find_all('source'):
    FIXTV = vid['src']
```

now there is only one "text",
what can be done at this time?

**No listen URL! SID not found!**

it wouldn't bother me so much if the link didn't work, but when printing, if there is a "broken" link in the links, the whole thing doesn't work

in this example the CINELIFEHD works, as soon as I add FIXTV the print no longer works because of the changed page

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_url55 = "http://streamstat.net/videoplayer.cgi?sid=14358315&ext=.m3u8"
html_response = requests.get(html_url55)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_response.text, 'html.parser')
for vid in soup.find_all('source'):
        CINELIFEHD = vid['src']


html_url23 = "http://streamstat.net/videoplayer.cgi?sid=148177550&ext=.m3u8"
html_response = requests.get(html_url23)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_response.text, 'html.parser')
for vid in soup.find_all('source'):
        FIXTV = vid['src']


print(
    "#EXTM3U"
     + '\n' +"#EXTINF:0,tvg-logo=https://cinelife.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/cinelife_logo.png, CINE LIFE HD" + '\n' +
    CINELIFEHD
    + '\n' + "#EXTINF:0,tvg-logo=http://1241.hu/userfiles/image/tvcsatornak/pic_atkoto_55_fix_tv.png, Fix" + '\n' +
    FIXTV
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


keys = [148177550, 14358315]

params = {
    'ext': '.m3u8'
}


def get_soup(content):
    return BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        for k in keys:
            params['sid'] = k
            r = req.get(url, params=params)
            soup = get_soup(r.text)
            try:
                goal = soup.select_one('source')['src']
            except TypeError:
                goal = "N/A"
            print("Key: {:10}, Result: {}".format(k, goal))


main('http://streamstat.net/videoplayer.cgi')
```

Output:

```
Key:  148177550, Result: N/A
Key:   14358315, Result: https://magselect-stirr.amagi.tv/playlist1080p.m3u8
```

Comment: thanks for the reply if anyone wants to group the links this is probably a good solution but if you look at my print
you will see that each link get is different e.g. the link to the logo or the channel name
is it possible with your script to make it look like my print?

Comment: I don’t understand your question at all

Comment: your script is based on the group, so a link would get the same logo and name because only the url comes from the page 
is `"#EXTINF:0,tvg-logo=https://cinelife.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/cinelife_logo.png, CINE LIFE HD"`
is added manually to each link and they are all different

Comment: Sorry which group ? I’m having hard time to understand what you are saying . Maybe someone other may be able to help as I totally can’t understand you

Comment: keys = [148177550, 14358315]
goal is the group of links

`print("#EXTM3U")
def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        for k in keys:
            params['sid'] = k
            r = req.get(url, params=params)
            soup = get_soup(r.text)
            try:
                goal = soup.select_one('source')['src']
            except TypeError:
                goal = ""

            print("#EXTINF:0,"+goal)`
goal collects all links together so I can't "print" to just one link

Comment: sadly they don't come to help much...
I'll try to explain it another way
Keys = [148177550, 14358315, 119413429, 39674391, 39673726 ]
for example if there are 50 numbers in Keys how can I refer one of them in the print and not all of them? e.g. only just 119413429 that prints the link behind it https://cdnlive.myspirit.tv/LS-ATL-43240-2/index.m3u8